# Output in FunctionExpand for function of Gamma

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting, special-functions

I used of this code:

```
α Gamma[α] // FunctionExpand
```

and get output:

```
Gamma[1 + α]
```

Also I used of this code:

```
(α + α^2) Gamma[α] // FunctionExpand
```

output is:

```
Gamma[2 + α]
```

Please consider:

```
(0.9 x^α)/(α Gamma[α]) - (
  0.1 x^(1 + α))/((α + α^2) Gamma[α]) //   FunctionExpand
```

which output is:

```
(0.9 x^α)/(α Gamma[α]) - (
 0.1 x^(1 + α))/((α + α^2) Gamma[α])
```

I want output which is:

```
(0.9` x^α)/Gamma[1 + α] - (0.1` x^(1 + α))/
 Gamma[2 + α]
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I understand it you can reduce your problem to FunctionExpand[0.9 x Gamma[x]] giving 0.9 x Gamma[x] instead of 0.9 Gamma[1+x] which can, however be found using FunctionExpand[a x Gamma[x]]/.a->0.9

Comment: Alternatively, try using exact coefficients.

Comment: `expr // Rationalize // FullSimplify`